# IOS Swift Error parsing XML array using SwiftyXMLParser

Tags: ios, xml, swift, xml-parsing

Hi I'm parsing xml response from server using `SwiftyXMLParser`. I'm can successfully parse single xml but have problem with array value. always got nil

here is my sample xml

```
<ItemTrackingDetailsResponse xmlns="http://singpost.com/paw/ns" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ItemsTrackingDetailList>
        <ItemTrackingDetail>
            <TrackingNumber>SMT0000000628</TrackingNumber>
            <TrackingNumberFound>true</TrackingNumberFound>
            <AlternativeTrackingNumber/>
            <TrackingNumberActive>true</TrackingNumberActive>
            <PostingDate/>
            <InsuredValue/>
            <InsuredSDR/>
            <Weight/>
            <ExpressInd/>
            <ItemCategory/>
            <Content/>
            <PreadviceDate/>
            <ReceptacleID/>
            <OriginalCountry>Singapore</OriginalCountry>
            <DestinationCountry>Singapore</DestinationCountry>
            <ItemType>Speedpost</ItemType>
            <DeliveryStatusDetails>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>Recovered item from POPStation for service recovery</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-22T16:35:30</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160822 163530</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>Delivered to POPStation</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>POPStation@Yew Tee Square</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-16T17:27:48</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160816 172748</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>With Delivery Courier</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-16T11:25:00</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160816 112500</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>Received at Processing Facility</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-16T10:28:07</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160816 102807</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>Notification of shipment confirmation</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-13T11:10:29</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160813 111029</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
            </DeliveryStatusDetails>
        </ItemTrackingDetail>
    </ItemsTrackingDetailList>
    <Status>
        <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorDesc>Success</ErrorDesc>
    </Status>
</ItemTrackingDetailsResponse>
```

I can get single item by

```
print(xml!["ItemTrackingDetailsResponse","ItemsTrackingDetailList","ItemTrackingDetail","ItemType"].text)
```

but for the array I can not get the detail. How to access array member? Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

```
    <DeliveryStatusDetails>
                    <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                        <StatusDescription>Recovered item from POPStation for service recovery</StatusDescription>
                        <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                        <BeatNo/>
                        <Date>2016-08-22T16:35:30</Date>
                        <AceDate>20160822 163530</AceDate>
                    </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                        <StatusDescription>Delivered to POPStation</StatusDescription>
                        <Location>POPStation@Yew Tee Square</Location>
                        <BeatNo/>
                        <Date>2016-08-16T17:27:48</Date>
                        <AceDate>20160816 172748</AceDate>
                    </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                        <StatusDescription>With Delivery Courier</StatusDescription>
                        <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                        <BeatNo/>
                        <Date>2016-08-16T11:25:00</Date>
                        <AceDate>20160816 112500</AceDate>
                    </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                        <StatusDescription>Received at Processing Facility</StatusDescription>
                        <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                        <BeatNo/>
                        <Date>2016-08-16T10:28:07</Date>
                        <AceDate>20160816 102807</AceDate>
                    </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                        <StatusDescription>Notification of shipment confirmation</StatusDescription>
                        <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                        <BeatNo/>
                        <Date>2016-08-13T11:10:29</Date>
                        <AceDate>20160813 111029</AceDate>
                    </DeliveryStatusDetail>
</DeliveryStatusDetails>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Child Array content as follows:

```
print(xml["ItemTrackingDetailsResponse","ItemsTrackingDetailList","ItemTrackingDetail","DeliveryStatusDetails","DeliveryStatusDetail",0,"Location"].text)
```

The `"DeliveryStatusDetail",0` denotes that you want to access the 0th position `DeliveryStatusDetail` element.

To enumerate through the array:

```
for DeliveryStatusDetail in xml["ItemTrackingDetailsResponse","ItemsTrackingDetailList","ItemTrackingDetail","DeliveryStatusDetails","DeliveryStatusDetail"] {
    print(DeliveryStatusDetail["Location"].text)
}
```

Comment: work perfectly. Thanks a lot!. But how can we loop through the array?

Comment: thanks, it easier to work with XML now. Anyway we can print the whole xml (to test out whether response is correct)?

Comment: like a whole xml as a string so we can see what is inside!

Comment: Yes, use this code: `let datastring = String.init(data: xmlData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`